# sass variable not working in container query

Tags: sass, container-queries

SCSS variables don't seem to work when used in a container query. For example this code works just fine:

```scss
.parent {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background: yellow;
}

@container (max-width: 800px) {
  .child {
      background:green;
  }
}
```

See pen: https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/jOprKya

But when I try to use a sass-variable to define the breakpoint, it fails.

```scss
$width: 800px;

.parent {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background: yellow;
}

@container (max-width: $width) {
  .child {
      background:green;
  }
}
```

See pen: https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/BaPzVZW

What's the problem here? Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot find the definitive sass lang entry, but hash and curly brace is often used in `@media` queries.

```
@container (max-width: #{$width}) {
  .child {
      background:green;
  }
}
```

In `Brave` it works in that codepen; and so do the following:

```
@container (max-width: ${width} ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As "A Boston" already pointed out the issue seems to be that you don't use the hash syntax like in his first example.

I use https://www.sassmeister.com/ quite often to check what it compiles to.

In your Codepen you forgot to add a semicolon after

```
$width: 800px;
             ^
```

According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container
`@container` queries are not supported for Firefox yet. Only Firefox Nightly supports it.

I've tested it in Chrome and it worked with the tweaks. Make sure your browser version is supported. My current Safari version did not work either (due to the version mismatch).

Comment: Sassmeister.com has been invaluable. Good suggestion.